# Rails: Timezone difference on local and production

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have a Sidekiq worker, fetching records from a remote Oracle database and saving it in a postgres database. Most of the data consists of date and time fields. The issue I'm getting on production is that it saves the data time in different timezone with 5 hours difference. Although it works fine on local. Here is an example:

```
From Oracle DB => 2016-01-27 07:59:29 +0500

Saved on local => 2016-01-27 07:59:29 -0500

On Production  => 2016-01-27 02:59:29 -0500
```

In config/application.rb I have set:

```
config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

What should I do to make it consistent on both local and production?

Comment: You are using `Time.zone.now` ?

Comment: I'm taking the datatime as string and passing it as parameter to save the records

Comment: You have set `config.active_record.default_timezone` ?

Comment: No, I haven't set this

Comment: @kalelc What it should be?

Comment: `config.active_record.default_timezone` determines whether to use `Time.local` (if set to `:local`) or `Time.utc` (if set to `:utc`) when pulling dates and times from the database. The default is `:utc`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102262/discussion-between-kalelc-and-arif).

Comment: So, In my case to make the records save as it is, what it should be?

Comment: You can try `Time.zone.parse('2016-01-27 07:59:29 +0500')` to save variable in record.

Answer (score 1):

check this http://www.elabs.se/blog/36-working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails, seems like your are doing some from the dont's section:

```
Time.now # Returns system time and ignores your configured time zone. (2015-08-27 14:09:36 +0200)
Time.parse("2015-08-27T12:09:36Z") # Will assume time string given is in the system's time zone. (2015-08-27 12:09:36 UTC)
Time.strptime("2015-08-27T12:09:36Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z") # Same problem as with Time.parse. (2015-08-27 12:09:36 UTC)
Date.today # This could be yesterday or tomorrow depending on the machine's time zone, see https://github.com/ramhoj/time-zone-article/issues/1 for more info. (Thu, 27 Aug 2015)
```

Comment: I'm not doing any of these

Comment: the link is dead

Answer (score 1):

to aviod problem with TimeZone, just use:

```
Date.current     # => Mon, 01 Feb 2016
DateTime.current # => Mon, 01 Feb 2016 17:32:18 +0000
Time.current     # => Mon, 01 Feb 2016 17:33:17 UTC +00:00
```

Comment: I'm not using any of these, just taking the time and saving it.